# How do I to get the full NTFS tree of the current computer?

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I to get the full NTFS tree of the the current computer?

Is this possible to implement?

Do I need to make a loop which browses the entire disk, save the path of each file/folder found and loop again the saved paths for display? But, how to get browse the different disks (C:\, E:..), knowing that I'm supposed to do not know what disks names are in my computer? And, the implementation of the described algorithm will not make the runtime very slow (catch paths + display)? Is there another better way to deal with this, please.

OS: Windows 7 64bits SP1.

Comment: For finding what drive letters you have on your computer you can use the [GetLogicalDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364972(v=vs.85).aspx) function or the [GetLogicalDriveStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975(v=vs.85).aspx) function. For browsing a folder for the files it contains use the [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: There's no NTFS tree. Windows disk systems use the forest model. Reading the entire forest can be timeconsuming, especially if one of the drives is a DVD.

Comment: Why do you want the whole tree? What are you trying to do? There may be a better way to do it.

Comment: This could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Ben, I'm trying to browse it from a remote computer.

Comment: Just browse to \\MACHINE\C$, \\MACHINE\D$ etc using Windows Explorer.